# lightopenID for university Google-hosted email

Tags: php, openid, lightopenid

I am currently experimenting with implementing an openID for a small website for college. I am very new to this and have followed up with related articles. I have downloaded lightopenId and uploaded the folder to my webserver.  My school has google hosting their email service so typical email addresses are: like this `studentlastname@myuniversity.edu`. We can login through `mail.google.com` or a custom web page designed by google specifically for our login `mail.google.com/a/oakland.edu/`.

Instead of having users be redirected to the general `$openid->identity = 'https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id';` can I have the users directed to the custom university google hosted page to authenticate?

Gives me error:

> No OpenID Server found at `http://mail.google.com/a/oakland.edu/accounts/o8/id`

openid.php:

```
<? 
    <?php
    require 'openid.php';
    try {
        # Change 'localhost' to your domain name.
        $openid = new LightOpenID('http://webprolearner.ueuo.com');
        if(!$openid->mode) {
            if(isset($_GET['login'])) {
                $openid->identity = 'mail.google.com/a/oakland.edu/accounts/o8/id';
                header('Location: ' . $openid->authUrl());
            }
    ?>
    <form action="?login" method="post">
        <button>Login with Google</button>
    </form>
    <?php
        } elseif($openid->mode == 'cancel') {
            echo 'User has canceled authentication!';
        } else {
            echo 'User ' . ($openid->validate() ? $openid->identity . ' has ' : 'has not ') . 'logged in.';
        }
    } catch(ErrorException $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, the correct identity in your case would be:

```
https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/site-xrds?hd=oakland.edu
```

This url returns a valid XRDS (so LightOpenID will find a server).

Note that if the server isn't configured properly, you might get a similar error when calling `validate()`.

Comment: Oh but yes i did get: No OpenID Server found at http://oakland.edu/openid?id=103676657823296937874. What can i do now?

Comment: Ask someone who can do it to return an xrds document at oakland.edu/openid, or redirect to it. For example, by including the following code: `<?php header('X-XRDS-Location:
https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/site-xrds?hd=oakland.edu'); ?>`. Unfortunately, there's no other way around it, unless you want to hack the library to check the "valid" url (and break the openid spec).

Comment: +1 Alright, I am starting to understand. I found another answer of yours in regards to the same subject. I will have to ask the school administrator to do that. How will the xrds document look like for my scenario? will a folder named `openid` need to be created  and then place the xrds document inside inside the school server?

Comment: `/openid` should send an X-XRDS-Location with the url I've mentioned in my previous comment (and my answer). If you can't do it, send a Location header redirecting to that url. If, and only if you can't do either, return a html file with `<meta http-equiv="X-XRDS-Location" content="https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/site-xrds?hd=oakland.edu">`. If you serve the file statically, you risk it breaking if google changes something.

Comment: thank you for being patient with me. I am new to this technology. I have edited my answer is that how the XRDS should look like inside the school server? Now i will have to redirect to that xdrs document?

Comment: No. The correct XRDS is at `https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/site-xrds?hd=oakland.edu`, and you should redirect to it (instead of copying it to your server).

Comment: haha sorry about my confusion. Just want to have this as clear as possible. so I will need to include this url redirect: `<?php header('X-XRDS-Location: https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/site-xrds?hd=oakland.edu'); ?>` somewhere in the school server? maybe inside this oakland.edu/index.php?

Comment: You have to include this redirect in the file that responds to http://oakland.edu/openid . Whether is it index.php, or another file, I have no way to know. In other words: LightOpenID will open http://oakland.edu/openid and look for X-XRDS-Location header. If it finds one, the validation can proceed. The error you are getting right now is because there's no such header at http://oakland.edu/openid .

Comment: Alright, I am right now at 85% of understanding this. When you refer to lightOpenID looking at X-XRDS-Location at `oakland.edu/openid`, Is that the same thing as `oakland.edu/openid.php`?

Comment: Generally no (that is, unless you configure the server to redirect `/openid` to `/openid.php`). Try to visit `oakland.edu/openid` and `oakland.edu/openid.php` in your browser. Is that the same thing (assuming that they're not both 404s)?

Comment: Oh alright, well then what is `openid` isnt that a php document?

Comment: It's a path, not necessarily a file. There's not enough space in this comment to precisely explain what's the difference, but putting it simply: Usually, the server sees a path like `/index.php`, so it finds `index.php` in a directory, then executes it and sends back the result. This is the default behavior, but by no means - the only one possible. Therefore, I can't say with certainty what would your server do upon a request for `/openid`. I have already described what should be the effect - there are many ways to achieve it, and I can't show you what exactly to do in your case.

Comment: Alright, well thank your for your patience and your help. When i do implement this into the school server. I will give you a heads up with  better details. Thanks again!